# Gitorious on CentOS

Tags: web-server, redhat, git, centos5

I need a quick tip..

I am looking to install gitorious
on a CentOS Box..

I found this tutorial on RHEL (Red Hat)..
http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Rhel_Installation

Will this work on CentOS?
(I Hear they're similar somehow (other than the fact their both linux))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS is binary-compatible with RHEL, and has the same software and packages with Red Hat trademarks removed. But one of the things that guide skips over is that not all of those packages are in the base repos. You'll need to install [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) as well.